# Solving ${\left( {\frac{{9.1}}{{10 - x}}} \right)^{0.1}} = {\left( {\frac{{9 + y}}{{9.1}}} \right)^{0.9}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

how to find real $x$ and $y$ such as ${\left( {\frac{{9.1}}{{10 - x}}} \right)^{0.1}} = {\left( {\frac{{9 + y}}{{9.1}}} \right)^{0.9}}$ ?

Comment: Are you asking to find a single pair of $(x,y)$ such that this is true?

Comment: @πr8 yes iam loking for $(x,y)$ suxh that is true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well solving for $y$ you get $y=9.1\times(\frac{9.1}{10-x})^\frac{1}{9}-9$. So just pick any $x$ not equal to $10$ and then find $y$ using the above formula.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that if each side is $1$, then the equation is verified. To make those fractions $1$, take $x = 0.9$ and $y = 0.1$.

Comment: The other answers given so far are more general than mine. I was under the impression, though, that the OP is looking for a solution made up of "simple" numbers.